# Handle on Window won’t fully open. Cams look misaligned

Tags: windows

The Top part of my cams (think that’s what they are called form some Googling) on my window are out of alignment with the bottom ones. When the window is closed the top cams are only half way down, this means there is not enough room for them to move up when I open the window so the handle on the window will not fully open. The bottom ones look in the right position.

I have included some pictures which show the problem. (They are also out of alignment in the top and bottom of the same window (pictures just show the middle part, but it’s the same at the top and bottom).

Does anyone please know how I fix this?

[image: Picture showing the problem and how it should look]

Comment: What brand/model are these windows? Have you taken a screwdriver to the metal trim to start removing things (take _LOTS_ of pictures as you do so in order to know how to put it back together) to see if there's something broken/wedged inside?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Allen wrench use inside]Those buttons are designed to use allen wrench on them.  You can see it as it is quite visible.

Therefore you should be able to loosen and move them where they need to be and then tighten them back up, using allen wrench.

Hope this helps.

Take care.

[Let me know if I am correct in that and it is the answer]

Answer (score 0):

I will take a SWAG: Those move pins into receptacle in the frame. Without aligning the window or making the receptacle slightly larger you will not get it to work properly. You could kluge it by milling/grinding down the pins just a small amount and add a taper if there is none so they slide into the receptacle.